# Access multiple elements of list not knowing their index

Tags: python

I'm working on a signal processing algorithm.

```
bool_carrierPhaseFlag = cosTwoDeltaPhi < 0.6
bool_CNRFlag = carrierToNoiseRatio < 25
if where(bool_carrierPhaseFlag) or where(bool_CNRFlag)
    print('Loss of tracking')
```

The booleans are arrays and I want the `if` condition to print "loss of tracking" when an array element is false using the above conditions.

Comment: Where is the `where` function coming from?

Comment: I tried to use where to access the True elements of the array. but it's not working. it's why i'm asking the command that i can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [all](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#all) builtin function to test whether *all* elements in a container evaluate to  `True`:

```
>>> arr = [True, True, False]
>>> if not all(arr):
...     print('One of us is False!')
... 
One of us is False!
```

Your code would look like this:

```
bool_carrierPhaseFlag = cosTwoDeltaPhi < 0.6
bool_CNRFlag = carrierToNoiseRatio < 25
if not all((bool_carrierPhaseFlag,bool_CNRFlag)):
    print('Loss of tracking')
```

Note the brackets to create a tuple from the arguments, `all` expects a single argument (or an un-bracketed generator expression if you are constructing an iterable on the fly).

`all` is a short-circuit operation, that is it will return `False` as soon as it finds an element in the container that evaluates to `False`, such as `False`, `None` or zero.

The [any](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#any) builtin function returns `True` if *any* element in a container is truthy.